# How should I tell flutter that my app needs rebuilding externally?

Tags: flutter

I want my app to get an intent, and depending on the intent to display something in the app.

Normally, when a widget depends on state, you put it in a State and run setState().

The issue is that when I try starting my flutter app with different intents, I  just get `I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 4472): onResume setting current activity to this`. And in a way it makes sense - I'm not saying anywhere in the **flutter** code that my widget needs repainting - since I get my intent through Java.

On the other hand, there should be a way to tell flutter to repaint my widget by intent? Or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically to get notified about `onResume` event you can use [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html). Implement its [didChangeAppLifecycleState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html) method and respond to [AppLifecycleState.resumed](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) by doing whatever it is you want the UI to do, such as call `setState` to trigger rebuild. That said, there needs to be an effective change for the UI to be repainted. Simply calling `setState` with no effective state change may not result (in fact, should not) in actual UI changes.

In general, you can send a message from Java (or Objective-C/Swift) to Flutter using [BasicMessageChannel](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/BasicMessageChannel-class.html) and make your app react to the message (e.g. call `setState` or schedule frames).

Comment: It works, thanks, but it I was still having issues that even when the app restarts `getIntent()` still only returns the intent the app originally started with (in contrast to Java, which reruns `onCreate` and updates `getIntent()`).